# What is $\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{n!}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, factorial

So recently a friend asked me to compute [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZMuI.jpg) limit:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty }\left(\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{n!}\right)$$

Question : Does the limit exist? If yes is it finite and if yes what is its value?

How do we solve this?

**Edit:**

Note: I am only familiar with only basics of limit solving(upto  L'Hôpital's rule) and have reasons to believe that this limit can be solved using these methods. If you could keep your answer simple that should help.

*Update*

Here is where I have gotten so far

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} (n+1)! ^{1\over n+1} - (n)! ^{1\over n}$$ 
Can be written as
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}[1*2*3*...(n+1)]^{1\over n+1}  - [1*2*3*...n] ^{1\over n}$$

$$\implies \lim_{n\to \infty} [(n+1)[{1 \over n+1}* {2 \over n+1}  * {3\over n+1}...* {n+1 \over n+1}]^{1 \over n+1} - (n)[{1 \over n}* {2 \over n}  * {3\over n}...* {n\over n}]^{1 \over n} ]$$

(Factoring n+1 out of first expression and n from second.)

$$\implies  \lim_{n\to \infty} [(n+1) e^{{1 \over n+1} (\sum_{r=1}^{n+1}ln({r\over n+1}))} - (n) e^{{1 \over n} (\sum_{r=1}^{n}ln({r\over n}))}  ]$$

From here I think second limit can be solved as a integral(limit of a sum) but I cannot solve first. How can I proceed further?

Thanks!

Comment: I think I may have very well started the question on wrong lines I suppose.

Comment: http://recreatiimatematice.ro/arhiva/nota/RM22003CARJA.pdf?i=1

Comment: @medicu please explain that link. I do not understand that language.

Comment: Do you know that $\frac{{\sqrt[n]{{n!}}}}{n} \to \frac{1}{e}$?

Comment: Not as an identity but I think I can reach there after some calculations. But I do know how e is defined as the limit.

Comment: @Gary I get that now from here (https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=89d5f8WUf1Y) . Now what?

Comment: Having this limit in your toolkit, you can employ the approach given in medicu's answer below.

Comment: @Gary but $$=\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n+1}$$ is given and  not $$=\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}$$. Are they both same?

Comment: They are the same. It follows from the very basics of limits:
$$
\lim \frac{{\sqrt[n]{{n!}}}}{{n + 1}} = \lim \left( {\frac{n}{{n + 1}} \cdot \frac{{\sqrt[n]{{n!}}}}{n}} \right) = \lim \frac{n}{{n + 1}} \cdot \lim \frac{{\sqrt[n]{{n!}}}}{n} = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{e} = \frac{1}{e}.
$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can provide a more elementary approach, assuming the limit exists.

By Stolz-Cesaro, the discrete version of L'Hôpital's rule, we have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}}1=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}$$

and by the root-to-ratio limit, we also have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\times\frac{n^n}{n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}$$

which, by the limit definition of $e$, is given by

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}=\frac1e$$

Comment: This is a Stolz-Cesaro reciprocal, which is not always true.

Comment: @medicu Hence why I said "assuming the limit exists". The remaining criterion for the reverse of Stolz-Cesaro are then satisfied.

Comment: I hate to say this but I do not know Stolz-Cesaro theorem. Can you try a even simpler method? Sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @HrishabhNayal It is unlikely. You can understand it as a variation of L'Hôpital's rule, where instead of using derivatives we use difference quotients with $\Delta x=1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @Simplt Beautiful Art    Thanks for that. I think I might try and study Stolz-Cesaro theorem(probably wikipedia it) and then look at this solution again.

Comment: A bit confusion how did you proceed after the line where it is written "root to ratio limit".? How can I reach $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac{n!}{n^n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\times\frac{n^n}{n!}$$.?

Comment: @HrishabhNayal It uses the fact that $$\sqrt[n]{a_n},~\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$ both approximate $a_n\simeq r^n$, which is in this case, $r=1/e$. For more information, see the ratio test and root test for finding the radius of convergence of a series.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106062/discussion-between-hrishabh-nayal-and-simply-beautiful-art).

Answer (score 5):

Brute force, but from the Stirling formula
$$
n! = \left( {\frac{n}{e}} \right)^n \sqrt {2\pi n} \left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right),
$$
one has
$$
\sqrt[n]{{n!}} = \frac{n}{e}\exp \left( {\frac{1}{2n}\log (2\pi n)} \right)\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^2 }}} \right)} \right) = \frac{n}{e} + \frac{1}{2e}\log (2\pi n) + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log ^2 n}}{n}} \right).
$$
This gives
$$
\sqrt[{n + 1}]{{(n + 1)!}} - \sqrt[n]{{n!}} = \frac{1}{e} + \frac{1}{2e}\log \left( {\frac{{n + 1}}{n}} \right) + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log ^2 n}}{n}} \right) = \frac{1}{e} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{\log ^2 n}}{n}} \right).
$$
Thus the limit is $1/e$.

Comment: So just some context I am familiar with only the basics of limits and have not reaches the point where i am familiar with Stirling formula. If you could try a more basic method?

Comment: Nonetheless this shows that limit is indeed finite. so +1  from me.

Answer (score 2):

Calculation of the limit expressing the difference in the statement by strings whose limit is known.
$$\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[n]{n!}
=\sqrt[n]{n!}\left(\frac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}-1\right)
=\sqrt[n]{n!}\cdot\frac{x_{n}-1}{\ln{x_{n}}}\cdot\ln\sqrt[n(n+1)]{\frac{(n+1)^n}{n!}}= $$
$$=\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n+1}\cdot\frac{x_{n}-1}{\ln{x_{n}}}
\cdot\ln\frac{n+1}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}\rightarrow \frac{1}{e}\cdot1\cdot\ln{e}=\frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: This is the string of Traian Lalescu, a Romanian mathematician.The problem may be solved on this site

Comment: Use `\left(\frac{sth}{sth}\right)` for the output $\left(\frac{sth}{sth}\right)$. (:

Comment: ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya. Thank you!

Comment: Medicu, you're welcome!

Comment: I understand the first line but lost it when you introduced logarithms(probably because I do not how strings work). Sorry for that. Meanwhile I changed my approach a bit(as updated in question) can you extend on those lines? Thanks for the answer btw. :)

Comment: @HrishabhNayal: you should note that $$x_n=\dfrac{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}}{\sqrt[n]{n!}}=\left(\frac{((n+1)!)^n}{(n!)^{n+1}}\right)^{1/n(n+1)}=\left(\frac{(n+1)^n}{n!}\right)^{1/n(n+1)}=\sqrt[n+1]{\frac{n+1}{\sqrt[n] {n!} }}$$ and further that $x_n\to 1$ and $x_n^{n+1}\to e$. These limits are proved using root to ratio theorem used in another answer which itself is based on Cesaro-Stolz.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh Why does  $x_n \rightarrow 1$ and $x_n^{n+1} \rightarrow e$. I cannot see it.

Comment: @medicu why does $=\frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n+1}$ tend to $1\over e$?

Comment: @HrishabhNayal: here is one simple approach to $$x_n^{n+1}=\dfrac{n+1}{\sqrt [n] {n!}} =\dfrac{n+1}{n}\cdot\dfrac{n}{\sqrt[n] {n!}} $$ The limit is same as that of $n/\sqrt[n] {n!} $ and taking logs this expression becomes $$-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log\frac{k}{n}$$ which tends to $-\int_{0}^{1}\log x\, dx=1$ and therefore original limit is $e$.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh: Your comments are quick and easy to understand. Thank you!

Comment: @Hrishabh Nayal :The limit in the last one comment is explained in the second answer to this question using the root criteria (Cauchy-D'Alembert).

Comment: By the way I have given my +1 already.

Answer (score 1):

So I'm providing a first-principles approach, after seeing that you're unable to understand most of the answers that were posted.

We know that 
$$n! = n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2) \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot 2 \cdot 1$$
Taking a logarithm both sides, we get 
$$\ln n! = \sum_{r=1}^n\ln r$$
Looking at this summation and comparing it with the $\ln x$ function, we see that they are pretty similar, especially as $n \to \infty$
[image: graph]
Since they are so similar, we can approximately replace the summation with a definite integral as follows:
$$\ln n! \approx \int_1^n \ln x dx = n\ln n - n + 1$$

This is the principle behind the **Stirling approximation**, the formula that Gary used in his answer. It's a rough approximation: a more precise one uses the Euler-MacLaurin series but since our limit involves the difference of two of these terms, we can use this approximation as the error would be subtracted.

Taking an exponent and the nth root both sides gives us a very usable form of the term $(n!)^\frac 1n$
$$n! = \left( \frac ne \right)^ne \implies (n!)^\frac 1n = \frac ne \cdot e^\frac 1n$$

Now we can simply substitute the values of $n+1$ and $n$ in the obtained function and find their difference to obtain the limit. This is a fairly simple task and makes use of the taylor series expansion of $e^x$, which you should know.

$$L = \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \space \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n+1]{(n+1)!}-\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{n!} = \frac {n+1}e\cdot\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n+1]{e} - \frac {n}e\cdot\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{e}$$

$$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac ne \left( \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n+1]{e} - \sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{e}\right) + \frac {\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}n]{e}}e$$

let $t \to 0 \implies n = \frac 1t$.

$$L = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac 1{et}\left( e^\frac{t}{t+1} - e^t \right) + \frac{e^\frac{t}{t+1}}{e}$$

Applying a taylor series expansion for $e^x$, we get

$$L = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac 1{et}\left( 1 + \frac t{t+1} + \frac {t^2}{(t+1)^2 \cdot 2!} + ... - 1 - t - \frac {t^2}{2!} - ...\right) + \frac {1 + \frac t{t+1} + \frac {t^2}{(t+1)^2 \cdot 2!} + ... }e$$
$$ = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac 1{e}\left( \frac {-t}{t+1} + O(t^2) \right) + \frac 1e$$
$$L = \frac 1e$$

which is the final answer.

Comment: I understand how this approximation  $$\ln n! \approx \int_1^n \ln x dx = n\ln n - n + 1$$
 is valid graphically but I think I could do with a more formal proof. Is there a simpler way than Euler-MacLaurin series?

Comment: you could use the Gamma function as shown in wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: Actually the person I have to explain this answer is a IIT JEE  aspirant(I assume you know what that explains about the knowledge of that person) so I am not sure he would understand Gamma function (let alone its integration). So if you could help me considering the knowledge of that person It would be very helpful . Btw +1 from me as you have really dumbed it down enough for me to understand :)

Comment: @HrishabhNayal I am an IIT JEE Aspirant myself and while I do understand the Gamma function, I solved it without the Gamma Function/Euler-MacLaurin series and provided a simple enough version in my answer. I don't think a more formal proof is required for Stirling's approximation.

Comment: Well I might run into trouble explaining him why that approximation works. They rarely use these type approximation in their preparation right?